# Intersections of open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that if $U$ is open in $X$ and $A$ is closed in $X$, then $U-A$ is open in $X$, and $A-U$ is closed in $X$?

So far I have that $X-A$ and $U$ are open, hence $U \cap (X-A)$ is open. I need to show that $U \cap (X-A)=U-A$, but I don't know how to do so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't put the actual question (only) in the title. The body should be readable (and make sense) without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \in U \cap (X \setminus A) $

iff [$x \in U$ *and* $x \in X$ *and* $x \notin A$]

iff [$x \in U$ *and* $x \notin A$] $ \ \ \ \ \ $   (since $U \subseteq X$ , [$x \in U$ *and* $x \in X$] iff $x \in U$)

iff  $x \in U \setminus A$.

Here I have just used the definitions.

Comment: You dropped a $x\in X$. There is no way to prove $U\cap(X\setminus A)=U\setminus A$ unless you invoke $U\subseteq X$ somewhere.

Comment: Look, in the second 'iff' I could have written "iff$ x \in U $and $x \in X$ and $x \notin A$". But since $U \subseteq X$ by assumption, this is obviously equivalent to what I wrote. I 'skipped a step'... ... ...!

Comment: Well yes you skipped a very simple step, but if you are going to prove something where the entire proof is itself so simple, the "proof" ends up just repeating the statement. As it is, it just looks like you go straight from the beginning to the end with no intervening steps.

Comment: OK, I have edited the post accordingly. Fair point.

Answer (score 1):

(Truly elementary) set theory can help a lot here:

Notice that for subsets $A,B$ of $X$, $A-B = A\cap B^c$ (where $B^c = X-B$).  This part you should do by looking at each elements (as done in @Frank's answer).

Also, notice another obvious fact $(A\cap B)\cap C = A\cap (B\cap C)$ (again, you could prove this, but really, it is very believable).

Now, $U\cap (X-A) = U\cap X \cap A^c = (U\cap X)\cap A^c = U \cap A^c = U - A$

There will come a time when reasoning by looking at each element will be quite cumbersome.  I recommend doing a brief study of elementary set theory (it really does help in the end!)